# How to check logical value of an expression in the interactive shell?

Tags: python, python-interactive

Sometimes I want to check the logical value of an expression, so I type it in Python (or IPython) and get the result:

```
>>> a==3
True
```

But in other cases it doesn't work that way (here string is None):

```
>>> string
>>>
```

So I check the logical value like this:

```
>>> if string: print('True')
...
>>>
```

Is there a shorter way for checking the logical value of an expression?
Any function that returns *True* or *False* the same way it will be evaluated in an *if*-condition?

Comment: you can test for None with `string is not None` which returns `False` in your example

Comment: I know. I want to check, if *string* returns *True* or *False* in an if-condition. But if I type *string* (the next line), I just get no result.

Comment: I have removed the assignment of string from the code block, so now it's clearer what I meant.

Comment: If `string` is `None` you'll always get no result, see @Martijn Pieter's answer for the reason why. There's no way around that, that's how the interpreter works. You need to explicitly test for `None` or convert it to a `bool` before printing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a shorter way for checking the logical value of an
>   expression?

Yes, it's the [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) function:

```
>>> string = None
>>> bool(string)
False
```

Answer (score 7):

All expressions **except those that produce `None`** are echoed.

If you execute an expression that doesn't result in data being echoed, then you probably have a `None` result. You can test for `None` explicitly:

```
>>> string = None
>>> string is None
True
```

Using `is None` produces a non-`None` result.

If you just wanted to test for the *boolean* value of an expression, use the [`bool()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool); it'll return a result following the standard [truth value testing rules](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

```
>>> string = None
>>> bool(string)
False
```

Again, this is guaranteed to not be `None` and echoed. You can't distinguish between `None` and other false-y values this way, however. An empty string `''` will also result in `False`, for example.

Another alternative is to explicitly print all expression results, using the [`repr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr):

```
>>> print(repr(string))
None
```

This then produces the exact same output as echoing does, with the single exception that `None` is printed too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, create a boolean directly from the expression, which will always be `True` or `False`:

```
>>> bool(string)
False
```

Answer (score 1):

`string is None` or `string is not None` will return the boolean you need.

```
>>> string = None
>>> string is None
>>> True
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But "bool()" is what I needed. If string = '', I also get False.

Comment: `string is None` returns a bool

Comment: You could just use `else:` here; the `elif` condition is the exact inverse of the `if` condition.

Comment: I wanted to mark the usage of `not`, I know that I could use `else` lol

Comment: @magicleon: I know that I can test if a string is None and I get a boolean value. But I prefer bool() as it seems to handle the expressions the same way as an if-clause: None -> False, '' -> False, ' ' -> True, '0' -> True, 'False' -> True

Comment: Oh understood. Sorry I didn't get what your need is then. Seems interesting by the way!

Comment: No problem. It's my fault that the question wasn't clear to everyone. Maybe that's the reason, I couldn't find the answer in Google ;-) Thanks, anyway!

Comment: Glad you've found that though. Happy coding!